# Three activity/view layout with gesture

Tags: android, view, android-activity, gesture

I'm very new to Android development and haven't developed with Java for about 10 years. That aside, I'm looking for some pointers as to how to go about my task.

All I want initially are three activities/views.

One activity/view per screen, layed out in a 1,2,3 horizontal view layout sideby side. Activity/view 2 being the default view loaded when the app is started.

[image]

I would then like to add gesture listeners to move between the three. Essentially sliding back and forth.

What sort of layout should be used and what is considered best practice?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is totally achievable. You have to design three activities. Declare Activity 2 like this in Android Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Use Fling/Swipe to fire Intent to move from Activity 2 to other activities.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your answer I will look into this more. Thank you.